# TFS user group not updating

Tags: tfs, active-directory

I have several security groups in AD.  When I select them to add to TFS the group shows the users but once I add the group it does not pull the users through. So I have empty groups in TFS but full groups in AD.

Comment: Could you try just restarting the TFS services?

Answer (score 0):

Changes you make to local or Active Directory groups **do not get reflected in TFS immediately.**

TFS Job Agent is responsible for running this sync, by default this run once an hour.

You could try to restart **TFS Job Agent service** to see whether it helps. Also, check the article below to see whether it helps you:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24305.how-to-synchronize-tfs-users-with-ad-active-directory.aspx